# drop down value not post

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Thanks to some help here, I have a drop down in an html form.

```
<p>
    <select id="CategorySelection">
        <option value="0">Choose One</option>
        <option value="Research">Research</option>
        <option value="Innovation">Innovation</option>
        <option value="Application">Application</option>
        <option value="Integration">Integration</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Depending on what you choose - javascript shows different questions to follow this. The following questions and everything else are posting to the db (mysql) table fine.  I can't get this value to post- it just shows NULL.  Is there something I am missing because of the javascript?  I am really new in that area. Thanks!

Comment: how exactly u are getting the value in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST values derive from the name attribute, not the id. Your select just needs a name, like this:

```
 <select name="CategorySelection" id="CategorySelection">
```

Then you can access its value in the $_POST array as usual:

```
if (isset($_POST['CategorySelection'])){
    $category = $_POST['CategorySelection'];
}
```

Comment: So easy once I see it, but so hard when floundering! Thanks IarsAnders!

Answer (score 1):

You set the select attribute "id" to a value, you need to set a "name" attribute to it and then call that key from the $_POST array from the PHP.